# Cannot retrieve single item from an array stored in the state of React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, axios

Before I get bashed: "I am new to React!"

The url to the .json file is:

[JSON FOR GETTING QUOTES](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json%22asdf%22)

I am maintaining a state in my app which holds an array of quotes and the key value inside it.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        quotes: [],
        key: 0
    };
    this.handleClick= this.handleClick.bind(this)
}
```

The state is updated on getting a request to the url using axios.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json';

    axios.get(url).then((res) =>{
        const items = (res.data.quotes)
        this.setState({quotes: items})
        console.log(this.state)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Then I wish to pass get only one quote each time a click is made on the button.
For which I render a "DivElement" passing a specific quote as a prop as following:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Click Me
        </button>
        <DivElement
        currentquote = {this.state.quotes[this.state.key].quotes}
        />
        </div>
    );
}
```

"DivElement" declaration:

```
function DivElement(props){
console.log(props.currentquote)
return <p>{props.currentquote}</p>}
```

This is the TypeError I get:

```
TypeError: this.state.quotes[this.state.key] is undefined
```

Things I have tried:

**Didn't work** Use JSON.parse method to set the state.

What I wish to do: To display a random quote based on random key generated by onClick method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No render is asynchronous and it doesn't wait for API callback.

---

you have to conditionally render your component like this:

```
 render() {
    return (
      this.state.quotes.length && ( <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Click Me
          </button>
          <DivElement
            currentquote={this.state.quotes[this.state.key].quotes}
          />
      </div> )
    );
  }
}
```

Please let me know if the issue still persists,

Comment: Would appreciate an explanation for the "&&" operator here.

Comment: what error do you get please share? unless  your quotes length becomes greater than one the code block comes after && will not be rendered

Comment: ./src/App.js
Syntax error: C:/Users/Dell/Documents/Freecodecamp Projects/random_quote_machine/src/App.js: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (55:16)

  53 |                     Click Me
  54 |                 </button>
> 55 |                 <DivElement
     |                 ^
  56 |                     currentquote = {this.state.quotes[this.state.key].quotes}
  57 |                     />
  58 |                 }

Comment: there's missing closing tag in DivElement probably in App.js, not in here you should check your code. Or you can share codesandbox here for better understanding

Comment: Edited my code. there was missing parent element while doing conditional rendering. here is you updated code: https://codesandbox.io/s/k02pvz6zqv

Comment: Thanks a ton! Works like a charm now!

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar issue again. When I do the conditional rendering with state holding the values I get the desired output, but instead when I create another variable to hold the value it doesn't render

Comment: Can you share codesandbox? Without code It’s hard to debug it

Comment: You need to put gamrOptions in your state, The reason you can only re render with `setState`. If you set callback res to a variable you component will not re render this way